# PHP array to json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I must be doing something stupid here.
I have this php file:

```
$arr = array("result" => "dasdasds;bks fjsdgjdklsds j&*", "text" =>"23 + 2   = &#160; ?");

echo json_encode($arr);
```

And I call it in my js file:

```
/*
   * PHP array to json
   */

  $("#jsonform").submit(function(e){

      $.ajax({
          url:"/phparraytojson/Helper.php", 
          success: function(data){ 
             console.log(data.result) //undefined
             console.log(data); //{"result":"dasdasds;bks fjsdgjdklsds j&*","text":"23 + 2 = &#160; ?"} 
          }

      })
      e.preventDefault();
  })
```

Comment: What exactly is your error? Don't you mind adding more information to your question?

Comment: use  dataType: "json",

Comment: I get undefined when calling data.result

Comment: Just a side notice, if you are going to output JSON on your server you should adjust the headers accordingly, place next line as first in your script  : `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding dataType: "json" should fix this:

```
$.ajax({
      url:"/phparraytojson/Helper.php", 
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){ 
         console.log(data.result) //undefined
         console.log(data); //{"result":"dasdasds;bks fjsdgjdklsds j&*","text":"23 + 2 = &#160; ?"} 
      }

  })
```

Answer (score 1):

In ajax call you have to add format of output you are receiving from php. ie:
`dataType:"json"`

```
$("#jsonform").submit(function(e){

  $.ajax({
      url:"/phparraytojson/Helper.php", 
      dataType:"json",              //Dont miss to add
      success: function(data){ 
         console.log(data.result) //undefined
         console.log(data); //{"result":"dasdasds;bks fjsdgjdklsds j&*","text":"23 + 2 = &#160; ?"} 
      }

  })
  e.preventDefault();  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you should be use datatype:'json' in ajax call
$.ajax({
    url:"/phparraytojson/Helper.php", 
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){ 
       console.log(data.result) //undefined
       console.log(data); //{"result":"dasdasds;bks fjsdgjdklsds j&*","text":"23 + 2 = &#160; ?"
                   } 
     }

});
```